# Multiselect : Copy values from one select to other on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't use any server side code, but I bet this is relatively easy in jQuery. I have two forms, each with a multiple select menu with identical data. If the user selects anything from the first select menu, I need them selected on the next menu if they click a button. I'm messing around with:

```
$("#AgentX").val($("#AgentZ")).change();
```

But nothing yet; any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: there is so much `select`... lol

Comment: lol! I know, I laughed as I typed the title, trying to reword it, yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you want:

```js
$(".copySelect").on("click", function() {
   $("#secondSelect").val($("#firstSelect").val());
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="first" id="firstSelect" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="second" id="secondSelect" multiple>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button class="copySelect">copy</button>
```

Comment: It does, thank you; I'd actually had it before - I had the ID spelled incorrectly (gahhhh!)..